# Jive - Apache Filter

Tags: module, filter, apache

I am currently trying to learn how to create apache filters to work within Jive, and have been trying to start small and work into what I need.

My issue right now is that I cannot seem to get a basic filter to work. I have followed a few different tutorials on creating and installing, as well as searching this site and many others, but I cannot seem to get any results and do not believe my filter is even being used.

Code:

```
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_config.h"
#include "http_core.h"
#include "http_log.h"
#include "http_protocol.h"

#include "ap_compat.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *p);
static int test_filter(request_rec *r);
static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *p)
{
    ap_hook_handler(test_filter, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE);
}

static int test_filter(request_rec *r)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("/usr/local/jive/var/logs/filter.log", "a+");
    fprintf(file, "In the Filter!\n");
    fclose(file);

    return OK;
}

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA test_module =
{
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    register_hooks
};
```

I compile and install the filter using:

```
apxs -c -i -a /mod_test.c
```

And I can see in the httpd.config file that the module is installed, so I add to the .config:

```
AddOutputFilter test-module
```

And finally, I perform a jive-httpd restart. In the end, the file I am trying to write to is never created or appended to. I am at a complete loss as to what to do now before I can move forward.

Running Jive SBS 4.5.4.0, with Apache/2.2.3 Httpd server.

Any help would be appreciated, and I apologize in advance if my formatting is off.